# Constructing a class in java, adding labels to two seperate panels gui, driver class and main class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, constructor

I am trying to add labels onto two different panels, using an oo method. But when i create the panels in my main class they cannot be seen in my driver class. I have just started to learn oo concepts. If i instantiate the panels in my driver class it works but not when I instantiate in the main class, which is the way I am being told.

Main Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class borderMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Border Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        borderpanel  p1 = new borderpanel();
        borderpanel p2 = new borderpanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Driver Class- When I do `p1.add(lbl1);` this is where I am getting the error

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class borderpanel extends JPanel {
       private JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3;
       private JTextField txt1;

     public borderpanel(){
         lbl1 = new JLabel("Hello");
         lbl2 = new JLabel("Hi");
         lbl3 = new JLabel("Hey");

         txt1 = new JTextField("Hello"); 

         p1.add(lbl1);
         p2.add(lbl2);
         p1.add(lbl3);
         p2.add(txt1);
         }
}
```

Comment: i guess you want `this.add`, as `borderpanel` (classes in camel case as `Borderpanel` for naming convention) as your `borderpanel` is the actuall `JPanel` you are using.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to add all the `JLabel` and `JTextField` objects you create to both instances of `borderpanel`? or add `lbl1` and `lbl2` to `borderpanel` `p1` and `lbl3` and `txt1` to the other `borderpanel` `p2`. In either case what you're doing at the moment will not work since `p1` and `p2` do not exist in the scope you are trying to access them from. Additionally, classes should be in `CamelCase` with an upper case letter to start with, e.g. `BorderPanel` and `BorderMain`

Comment: @d.j.brown I am trying to add lbl1, lbl2 to borderpanel p1 and the others to p2. Should i just instantiate p1 and p2 within the borderpanel() class

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: 4) There is no real case here for extending `JPanel`. Just create two panels in the `borderMain` class and add the appropriate labels or text fields to each. 5) The main problem currently is the **scope** of `p1` & `p2`. Neither is defined or accessible within the `borderpanel` constructor. 6) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because you are trying to access variables in `BorderMain` class within the `BorderPanel` class. You cannot access variables in a one class from another class like this. According to your comment

> I am trying to add lbl1, lbl2 to borderpanel p1 and the others to p2.

and if this is what you really need to do there is no need of having separate class as `BorderPanel`. You can do that like this.

**BorderMain**

```
public class BorderMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3;
        JTextField txt1;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Border Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        borderpanel  p1 = new borderpanel();
        borderpanel p2 = new borderpanel();

        lbl1 = new JLabel("Hello");
        lbl2 = new JLabel("Hi");
        lbl3 = new JLabel("Hey");

        txt1 = new JTextField("Hello"); 

        p1.add(lbl1);
        p2.add(lbl2);
        p1.add(lbl3);
        p2.add(txt1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**BorderPanel**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BorderPanel extends JPanel {

    public borderpanel(){}
}
```

But here `BorderPanel` is useless unless you are learning something regarding inheritance since it just a subclass of `JPanel`. You can do the same with `JPanel` also.

Answer (score 0):

```
public borderpanel(String message, String message2){
     lbl1 = new JLabel(message);
     txt1 = new JTextField(message2); 
}
```

Then you can have getters for the two fields lbl1 and txt1. Possibly then use the getters on the frame.getContentPane().add() method. Instead of having lbl1, lbl2 and lbl3, you can instead just instantiate the borderpanel; with p1 and p2.